# spark schema difference in partitions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have to read data from a path which is partitioned by region.

US region has columns a,b,c,d,e
EUR region has only a,b,c,d

When I read data from the path and doing a printSchema, I am seeing only a,b,c,d 'e' is missing.

Is there any way to handle this situation? Like column e automatically gets populated with null for EUR data...?

Comment: Need more info.

Comment: What's your data format?

Comment: I added an answer using pyspark. please see the answer and get back to me if you need any support or enhancement,  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mergeSchema` option that should do exactly what you are looking for as long as columns with the same name have the same type.

Example:

```py
spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").format("parquet").load(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had figured this out and this works for parquet

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for CSV files. From testing works with parquet files though

Comment: Yes this work only for formats that have a schema like parquet or ORC for example.

Answer (score 0):

Once you read the data from the path, you can check if data frame contains column 'e'. If it does not, then you could add this with default value which is None is this case.

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
                        .appName('example') \
                        .getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
    if 'e' not in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn('e',lit(None))
```

Comment: Hi Kapil, there are total 1200 columns in US and just 140 columns in EUR. So I cannot manually add each and every column via code. Also column 'e' has values for US .In the above snippet u shared, e is hardcoded with none...

Comment: Could you add some more details with code and data . that would help to replicate issue and provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all the possible columns from both dataset then fill None if that column is not available in each dataset

```py
df_ab = (spark
    .sparkContext
    .parallelize([
        ('a1', 'b1'),
        ('a2', 'b2'),
    ])
    .toDF(['a', 'b'])
)

df_ab.show()
# +---+---+
# |  a|  b|
# +---+---+
# | a1| b1|
# | a2| b2|
# +---+---+

df_abcd = (spark
    .sparkContext
    .parallelize([
        ('a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3'),
        ('a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4'),
    ])
    .toDF(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
)
df_abcd.show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|  d|
# +---+---+---+---+
# | a3| b3| c3| d3|
# | a4| b4| c4| d4|
# +---+---+---+---+

unique_columns = list(set(df_ab.columns + df_abcd.columns))
# ['d', 'b', 'a', 'c']

for col in unique_columns:
    if col not in df_ab.columns:
        df_ab = df_ab.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))
    if col not in df_abcd.columns:
        df_abcd = df_abcd.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))

df_ab.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- a: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- b: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- d: null (nullable = true)
#  |-- c: null (nullable = true)

df_ab.show()
# +---+---+----+----+
# |  a|  b|   d|   c|
# +---+---+----+----+
# | a1| b1|null|null|
# | a2| b2|null|null|
# +---+---+----+----+
    
df_abcd.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- a: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- b: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- c: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- d: string (nullable = true)

df_abcd.show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|  d|
# +---+---+---+---+
# | a3| b3| c3| d3|
# | a4| b4| c4| d4|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I used pyspark and SQLContext.  Hope this implementation will help you to get an idea. Spark provides an environment to use SQL and it is very convenient to use SPARK SQL for these type of things.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import sys
import os        
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

class getData(object):
"""docstring for getData"""

  def __init__(self):
  def get_data(self, n):
    
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('YourProjectName').getOrCreate()

    data2 = [("region 1","region 2","region 3","region 4"),
            ("region 5","region 6","region 7","region 8")
            
            ]

    schema = StructType([ \
                StructField("a",StringType(),True), \
                StructField("b",StringType(),True), \
                StructField("c",StringType(),True), \
                StructField("d", StringType(), True) \
                
                ])

    data3 = [("EU region 1","EU region 2","EU region 3"),
            ("EU region 5","EU region 6","EU region 7")
            
            ]

    schema3 = StructType([ \
                StructField("a",StringType(),True), \
                StructField("b",StringType(),True), \
                StructField("c",StringType(),True) \
                
                
                ])

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("USRegion")
    sqlDF = self.sparkSession1.sql("SELECT * FROM USRegion")
    sqlDF.show(n=600)

    df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data3,schema=schema3)
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView("EURegion")
    sqlDF1 = self.sparkSession1.sql("SELECT * FROM EURegion")
    sqlDF1.show(n=600)
    

    sql_union_df = self.sparkSession1.sql("SELECT a, b, c, d FROM USRegion  uNION ALL SELECT a,b, c, '' as d FROM EURegion ")
    sql_union_df.show(n=600)


#call the class
conn = getData()
#call the method implemented inside the class
print(conn.get_data(10))
```

[image: Answer]

Comment: Let me know if you need more support in this. I am happy to help :)